# PhoneGap Direct user to safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, safari, cordova

I am developing a iphone app using phoneGap. How can I direct user to safari when he clicks on a link or button inside of the application.

example:
 When user taps a button, safari browser will come to front and load corresponding site.

Comment: Actually it was very simple this line simply did the magic.

location.href="http://www.google.com"

Comment: you should answer your own question below

Answer (score 0):

you can use the childbrowser plugin to do that. Take a look here: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

Answer (score 0):

This line just worked for me..

```
 location.href="http://www.google.com";
```